# gData Youtube Feed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdata

I have built an applicaiton to load in a youtube feed and display it in a UITableView.

I have also added the ability to click a "Load More" cell which appears at the end of the Table which is meant to use the feeds nextLink and load 10 more videos which should populate the end of the table.

The problem is however, the table gets completely replaced with the new 10 items, instead of adding to what is already being displayed.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[feed nextLink] href]);
NSURL *feedURL; 
feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [[feed nextLink] href]]; 

GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
ticket = [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL delegate:self     
didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
```

And the below method:

```
- (void)request:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedBase *)aFeed
error:(NSError *)error {

self.feed =  (GDataFeedYouTubeVideo *)aFeed;


[superTable reloadData];
}
```

Does anyone know of a better way or if I can combine the contents of an existing feed with the new one I fetch? ie....If when the application loads it gets videos 1 - 10, do I need to refetch 1-20 or can I simply get 11-20 and add them to the tables datasource?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the entries of one feed to another, so long as you remove their parent pointer to their original feed like

```
NSArray *newEntries = [newFeed entries];

for (GDataEntryBase *entry in newEntries) {
  [entry setParent:nil];
  [previousFeed addEntry:entry];
}
```

If you are retrieving entries from the server by index, there is no guarantee that the entries in the second feed were not also in the first feed if the feed order has changed between fetches.

If the feed is not huge, you can fetch all pages of it at once by calling setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks: on the service object.